# Fail2ban logging correct ip on Varnish but still not locked out

Tags: wordpress, httpd, varnish, fail2ban

I am trying to configure`fail2ban` to ban bad `WordPress` login attempts, but I'm not having much success.

I am using [WP fail2ban 3.0.0](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-fail2ban/), which correctly logs bad login attempts on `/var/log/secure`, as far as I can tell (if anybody is interested, I am providing below my configuration for the plugin):

```
Apr 19 18:21:42 droplet wordpress(website.com)[17157]: Authentication failure for admin from my.ip.add.ress
```

The `filter` seems also to be configured correctly. In fact, if I run `fail2ban-client status wordpress` I can see my ip getting banned:

```
Status for the jail: wordpress
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 2
|  |- Total failed: 15
|  `- File list:    /var/log/secure
`- Actions
   |- Currently banned: 1
   |- Total banned: 1
   `- Banned IP list:   my.ip.add.ress
```

And also `fail2ban-regex /var/log/secure /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/wordpress.conf` finds `Failregex: 102 total`.

Still, I am perfectly capable of browsing the website and access the login page.

Of course there is something still missing, maybe on the Varnish side? I couldn't really find out, any idea?

I am running `CentOS 7.2.1511`, `Apache/2.4.6`, and `Varnish 4.0.3`.

---

In case anybody is interested, here is how I configured `WP fail2ban` to make it working with `Varnish`:

1. Enabled the plugin
2. Copied over the file `wordpress.conf` (contained in the plugin folder) into `/etc/fail2ban/filters.d/`
3. Added the following lines to `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local`

   ```
   [wordpress]
   enabled = true
   port = http,https
   filter = wordpress
   logpath = /var/log/secure
   ```
4. Added the following lines to `wp-config.php`:

   ```
   define('WP_FAIL2BAN_PROXIES','my.ser.ver.ip');
   define('WP_FAIL2BAN_AUTH_LOG',LOG_AUTHPRIV);
   ```
5. Added the following lines into `/etc/varnish/default.vcl` in the `sub vcl_recv` block:

   ```
   if (req.restarts == 0) {
       if (req.http.X-Forwarded-For) {
           set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
       } else {
           set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
       }
   }
   ```
6. Added the following lines into `/etc/varnish/default.vcl` in the `sub vcl_pipe` block:

   ```
   set bereq.http.connection = "close";
   return (pipe);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found the answer. I simply had to add the ban action in the relevant `jail.local` block. So now it looks like this:

```
[wordpress]
enabled = true
port = http,https
filter = wordpress
logpath = /var/log/secure
action = iptables-allports
```